# jquery fadein and fadeout simultaneously

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I want to make something like a menu so each menu item contain different content, but I do not want page reload. So I've made something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $hide = $('div#hide'),
        $home = $('div.home'),
        $download = $('div.download'),
        $about = $('div.about'),
        $contact = $('div.contact');

    $hide.css('display', 'none');

    $('a.home').on('click', function() {
        $hide.fadeOut();
        $home.delay(300).fadeIn(2000);
    });

    $('a.download').on('click', function() {
        $hide.fadeOut();
        $download.delay(300).fadeIn(2000);
    });

    $('a.about').on('click', function() {
        $hide.fadeOut();
        $about.delay(300).fadeIn(2000);
    });

    $('a.contact').on('click', function() {
        $hide.fadeOut();
        $contact.delay(300).fadeIn(2000);
    });
});​
```

Now... I believe that this could be way more cleaner and simplified but I cannot think of anything. I am basically new into jQuery...

Everything works fine, however I have two questions.
1) Can you make this script cleaner a bit?
2) Can you tell me how to load content simultaneously... Currently when home is loaded and I click download, it sort of jump while fadeIn...

Comment: Can you please post your HTML as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preventDefault()` method of the `event` object which prevents the default action of the event.

```
$('a.home, a.download, a.about, a.contact').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var cls = this.className;
    $hide.fadeOut();
    $('.'+cls).delay(300).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Comment: don't forget to change `$hide,$home` - or else they will all affect only those divs - actually hide is an ID so that one doesn't matter

Comment: Uh thank you for edit... Now this looks hella short and complicated but works great. Thank you for this.

Comment: Sure, this answers his question but it doesn't point out all of his problems. You shouldn't use CSS classes to determine the behavior. I also guess the containers for home, download, about and contact exists only one, and should therefor use ids and not classes.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall You are correct, but unfortunately OP hadn't posted the markup, of course using IDs is better but for targeting the IDs there should be other helpers like `href` or `data` attributes.

Comment: @undefined Then you should have asked for it instead of answering just for kicks. I also doesn't see where `preventDefault` has anything to do with his problem. Not to be rude, but you are teaching bad practice with this answer...

Comment: @MarcusEkwall I'm not teaching this practice as the best one and I'm not teacher. That's not true, `preventDeafult` was one of the main problems, read the question again.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall So you mean classes are bad for behaviors, how do you know that they are not used for styling purposes as well? and Why there are class selectors? Who says that using classes is not good? your comments are weird not the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't posted your HTML I can only guess what you are trying to achieve here, but based on that here's a couple of pointers:

- The `div` elements containing your content (home, download, about, contact) probably exists only once, and should therefor have ids and not classes
- When hooking onto the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event, make sure to use [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to stop the default event to trigger
- CSS classes should be used to style elements, not to define JavaScript behavior

With the above taken into consideration I've created an example that uses anchors to point to the element id in the `href` attribute by using a hash, and then use that to determine which element to show.

#### HTML

```
<nav>
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#download">Download</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</nav>

<div id="container">

    <div id="home">
        Home
    </div>

    <div id="download">
        Download
    </div>

    <div id="about">
        About
    </div>

    <div id="contact">
        Contact
    </div>

</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function(){
    var $menuItems = $('nav a'),
        $container = $("#container");

    $menuItems.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this.hash, $container).delay(300).fadeIn(1000).siblings().fadeOut(1000);
    }).first().click();
});​
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/y4Ujd/) on how the above works. Notice that I've removed the hide element since I have no idea what that is used for.

Comment: Well... I was in rush to make this functional :] !
However this seems to be working way better and I dont know exact reasons in difference but here is why this is better.

If clicked on same page, it doesnt fade it Out/In again.
I have used hide element to hide all stuff that should appear on menu click... so this is great clean.

However I am struggling with one thing in both cases.
It cannot find solution to make specified menu (example about) to remain selected on page reload. However I cannot even make home to appear as default (fadeIn). I think I might post new question. Cheers!

Comment: I've updated my example to select "Home" on load. It will be a lot more advanced to have it remember the selection. We are talking about cookies or using `history.pushState`. I will not cover this in my answer since it is outside of the question scope.

Comment: Yeh I clearly understand. However there is new question posted about this and only one guy had an reply with local storage which didn't worked for me. Cheers for this fix!

Comment: Mind linking to that question?

Comment: Sure man... Here's:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433587/specified-page-remain-selected-on-page-reload