# Specified page remain selected on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will post below html and javascript to make things clear... But before I do that, I will explain a bit what I am trying to accomplish.

Basically I want to make some pages to open without page reload. That was successfully done. Now, I cannot find any solution on how to make that page which is clicked, to remain opened on page load/reload.

```
<nav>
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#download">Download</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</nav>

<div id="container">
<div id="home">
    Home
</div>

<div id="download">
    Download
</div>

<div id="about">
    About
</div>

<div id="contact">
    Contact
</div>
</div>

$(function(){
var $menuItems = $('nav a'),
    $container = $("#container");

$menuItems.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this.hash, $container).delay(300).fadeIn(1000).siblings().fadeOut(1000);
});
});​
```

Thanks to Marcus Ekwall for help on the javascript!

Now... I am really wondering how can I use these href's to load clicked menu page when page is reloaded and also how to load home page on first visit. Cause what I get is blank page (no content) until I click on one of menu items.

Cheers.

Comment: if you want to say thanks to Marcus, just go +1 his answer

Comment: @Roko thanks... Was missing Reputation to +1 for his answer. Cheers :)

Comment: :D I know, that's why I +1'd your Q. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

If `localStorage` is ok for you?

```
$(function() {
    var $menuItems = $('nav a'),
        $container = $("#container");

    $menuItems.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this.hash, $container).delay(300).fadeIn(1000).siblings().fadeOut(1000);
        localStorage.setItem('currentpage', this.hash);
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentpage')) {
        $(localStorage.getItem('currentpage'), $container).siblings().hide();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Added a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b2aJ4/).

Comment: I have no ideas what localstorage is for... But no problems as long as it works. I tried what you wrote here and unfortunately theres no changes on page reload. Cheers.

Comment: Yeeh, that's the problem with localStorage. It's not supported by any browser, take a look: http://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage

Comment: I dont care about IE tho... However in demo works great but not on my page. When select contact for example and reload it shows display: none for content again... Strange :/ ! Well +1 for a shot!

Comment: Give me a link to your page and i can help you further ;)